# how to compile and link files in c programming?

Tags: c, linux

I am newbie to c programming language. I have the following files in same directory under centos linux system.

- game.c

  game.h

  main.c

**game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_
#define GAME_

extern void game (void);

#endif
```

**game.c**

```
#include "game.h"

void game (void)
{
   return 23;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "game.h"

int main (void)
{
    game();
}
```

when I compile using the following command..

```
gcc main.c
```

I get the error message as below..

> /tmp/ccwIlBKt.o: In function `main': main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined
>   reference to`game' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What is the correct way to link my header file?

Comment: You need to compile game.c too... (and not with a separate call, because then you would have to specify the linkage stuff yourself)

Comment: gcc -c game.c; gcc main.c -o app game.o

Comment: http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html

Comment: `return 23;` function game return type is void.

Answer (score 7):

You need to compile and link the two program.

First compile and create object files like this

```
gcc -c game.c

gcc -c main.c
```

Then you can generate executable file like this

```
gcc game.o main.o -o myexe
```

You can include library files using like this

```
gcc game.o main.o -o myexe -lsocket -wall
```

Here the lsocket is the socket library and using -wall displays if any warnings while linking the code

Comment: Using the -Wall command has always been recommended to me, so that you will notice any warnings while compiling.


'gcc -Wall game.c main.c' or 'gcc -Wall *.c'

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc game.c main.c
```

or

```
gcc *.c
```

You require to compile the `game.c`, where the function `game()` is implemented, that your main function (within `main.c`) is referring to.

Also you shouldn't be returning a value from a void function. Just leave the body blank, or if you really want a return statement, just type `return;`. i.e.

```
void game(void)
{
   return;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to return a value, change the declaration of the function to be:

```
<type-to-return> game(void)
{
    return /* value */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your code to this:

**game.c**

```
#include "game.h"
int game (void)
{
   return 23;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "game.h"
int main (void)
{
    game();
    return 0;
}
```

Your game.c needs to have the correct return type (int rather than void) and your main method should always return 0 when done to inform that the program ended correctly.

Also I can highly recommend this book when learning C (also good for references for experienced programmers):

C Programming Language, 2nd Edition by Brian W. Kernighan 
ISBN-13: 978-0131103627